# Age calculator for contact form

Tags: wordpress, datepicker, conditional-statements, contact-form, calculation

**Hi there,
Is it possible have date picker to calculate age!??
If age is less than 18 show some field and if age is = or more than 18 show other field.
Thanks in advance**

Comment: hi,can you show some example code to show how far you've got? More context would help someone answer your question, as well as showing that you're willing to put as much effort into a question as they might a response.   Also, your question does not need to be in bold, it comes across as shouting.

Comment: The plugin [CF7 Conditional Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-conditional-fields/) may be of use to you

Comment: The plugin Formidable forms Pro allows for conditionally hiding and showing fields based on the values of other fields. https://formidableforms.com/knowledgebase/using-conditional-logic/

Comment: CF7 Conditional Fields  is good but i need a plugin to pay once not monthly payment.